# How can I understand this JS issue?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, undefined-behavior

```js
var anObject = {left: 1, right: 2};
console.log(anObject.left);
// → 1
delete anObject.left;
console.log(anObject.left);
// → undefined
console.log("left" in anObject);
// → false
console.log("right" in anObject);
// → true
```

So, what I don't understand is how it's possible that after deleting the property `left`, it returns undefined when `console.log("left" in anObject);` shows to us that it doesn't exist anymore?

If `delete` deletes the property `left` from an object, it means that this property does not exists anymore, right? But if we see `undefined`, it means that the property still exists but has no value, right?

From [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) book:

> The difference between setting a property to undefined and actually
>   deleting it is that, in the first case, the object still has the
>   property (it just doesn’t have a very interesting value), whereas in
>   the second case the property is no longer present and in will return
>   false.

Comment: when accessing a nonexistent object property, it will be undefined. Thats how it is.

Comment: Where is the issue?

Comment: Please, read the quote from the book: "The difference between setting a property to undefined and actually deleting it is that, in the first case, the object still has the property (it just doesn’t have a very interesting value)". It means that property must be existed to show `undefined`. But in my case property can't be existed because it is deleted.

Comment: No, that’s not what the quote means. As many others have said, accessing a non-existing property returns undefined. And we can easily prove this: `var foo = {}; console.log(foo.bar);`. What the quoted text is implying is that even you get undefined *in both cases*, they are different because the property exists on one case and not in the other.

Answer (score 2):

From the same chapter of the book, right above the section you quoted, we find:

> ***Reading a property that doesn’t exist*** will produce the value `undefined`, which happens the first time we try to read the `wolf` property in the previous example.

The `wolf` example it references is here:

```
var day1 = {
  squirrel: false,
  events: ["work", "touched tree", "pizza", "running",
           "television"]
};
console.log(day1.squirrel);
// → false
console.log(day1.wolf);
// → undefined
day1.wolf = false;
console.log(day1.wolf);
// → false
```

Comment: "The difference between setting a property to undefined and actually deleting it is that, in the first case, the object still has the property (it just doesn’t have a very interesting value)". It means that property must be existed to show `undefined`. But in my case property can't be existed because it is deleted. So how it can be?

Comment: @AndreyMarchenko: What's the confusion? In the section before that, which I quoted, it explains that you'll get `undefined` when a property ***doesn't exist***. So the book answered your question. You get `undefined` for properties that do not exist, like the one you deleted.

Comment: @AndreyMarchenko: *”It means that property must be existed to show undefined.”* that’s not at all what the quote is saying. You are drawing the wrong conclusion. Setting a property to undefined does not imply that this is the only way accessing a property could return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` in JS should represent values of keys that are not defined for the given object. E.g., if my object is:

```
var foo = {a: "bar"};
```

And I try to access its non-existent property `b`, I will get `undefined`:

```
console.log(foo.b); // -> undefined
```

Similarly, if I delete the property `a`, I will get `undefined` afterwards:

```
console.log(foo.a); // -> "bar"
console.log("a" in foo); // -> true
delete foo.a;
console.log(foo.a); // -> undefined
console.log("a" in foo); // -> false
```

To further elaborate: the book is saying that there is a difference between a non-existent / deleted property on an object, and a property with the value `undefined`. I could, for example, set `foo.a` manually to `undefined`. Notice how the only way to differentiate the two is via the `in` operator:

```
foo.a = undefined;
console.log(foo.a); // -> undefined
console.log("a" in foo); // -> true
delete foo.a;
console.log(foo.a); // -> undefined
console.log("a" in foo); // -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(anObject.left);` Undefined is the expected behaviour because there is no property. False is a return value, which means that there actually is a property.

`console.log("left" in anObject);` here you ask 'is left in the object?' the return value of this function is simply true or false. If "left" had a value of 'false', it would return true!